# Self join- When i'm trying to do a self join, my query is displaying matching and non matching values

Tags: mysql, sql

Friends-

I have 2 tables, 1st one contains the details about history, 2nd contains details on current product details, i want to fetch the `product` whose `prod.description` has changed in the current. I got the answer for this.Now i have another table which contains both `current and history details` of the `product`, now i need the `products` whose `description` has changed, i'm trying this with `self join`,but i'm seeing both current and previous description

i have used the below query

```
select h.ProdName,h.ProdId, h.MfgDate, h.ProdDescription 
from historycurrent c join historycurrent h  on c.ProdId=h.ProdId where 
h.ProdDescription != c.ProdDescription;
```

[image]

[image: Query and Output] but i need only the last 3 records from the output.

Comment: You need to group the results by prodname, id and select the latest one (based on version or updated date)

Comment: Please provide with the historycurrent sample input

Comment: You need your mfgdate column to have time along with date to identify the latest record.

Comment: AjanBalakumaran yes i need all the columns

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do seems impossible with your current schema. This is because your table is de-normalized into a hybrid object table / transaction table. To produce the output you have, your table undoubtedly has six rows. The first three inserts added three objects ("D-Cold", "Otrivin" and "ZanduBalm") but the last three inserts updated those objects with a new description (and thus change the old records forever).

You need to split the table into two. So this:

```
create table historycurrent (
  ProdName VARCHAR(20),
  ProdId INT,
  MfgDate VARCHAR(20),
  ProdDescription VARCHAR(50)
  );
```

Needs to become (something like):

```
create table product (
  prodId INT PRIMARY KEY,
  prodName VARCHAR(?),
  mfgDate DATE
);

create table history (
  historyId INT,
  prodId INT, -- foreign key
  changeDate DATE,
  prodDescription VARCHAR(?)
);
```

Then you can query the history and do a simple join for the product info

Comment: I already got the expected answer with joining two tables, but I wanted to fetch the same output using selfjoin.